# How create this right join

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need create a view and I put for all transaction I need to associate all operation. If an operation is not present in TransactionOperation, I need to put in the result.

```
Transaction( transaction id,transaction_name)

Operation(id_operation,operation_name);

TransactionOperatation(id_transaction,id_operation); // represents all transaction to be used
```

So the view is:

```
Create view title AS select
t.id_transaction as id_transaction,
t.name_transaction as name_transaction,
o.id_operation as id_operation,
o.name_operation as name_operation,

from ((TransactionOperation to 
inner join transaction t on t.id_transaction=to.id_transaction)
rigth join operation o on o.id_operation=to.id_operation
```

The problem is that the associate is not working like I want it to. This must be the result for example:

```
Operation id_operation operation_name
           1            test
           2            home
transaction id_transaction  transaction_name
               1              scope
               2              pool

TransactionOperation id_operation operation_name id_transaction transaction name:
                         1            test          1             scope     
                         1            test          2             pool
```

In this example I need to obtain for every single transaction all operations. The operation with id=2 doesn't appear in TransactionOperation but must appear in the result. The result that I want is this

```
id_operation operation_name id_transaction transaction name:
   1            test          1              scope
   2            home          1              scope
   1            test          2              pool
   2            home          2              pool
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Operation id = 2 has no corresponding transaction. Why are you showing transactions corresponding to that in expected output ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya because I want these output! I know that there isn't!

Comment: There is no relationship between `id_operation=2` and `id_transaction=1`.  Why do you expect this record in your result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get all possible combinations between `transaction` and `operation`, despite not having a relationship defined between them in the junction table. This can be achieved using Cartesian product (`CROSS JOIN`) between the Unique values of the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW title AS
SELECT
  t.*, o.*
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT id_transaction, transaction_name FROM transaction) AS t
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT id_operation, operation_name FROM operation) AS o
```

Comment: why CROSS JOIN... I don't understand why with my LEFT/RIGHT JOIN it doesn't work. In my db I see the operation name with id=2 but there is like values id_transaction and transaction name a null value

Comment: @tttrrr because you are trying to get all possible combinations between transaction and operation, despite not having a relationship defined between them in the junction table.

Comment: yeas but with left/right (SUPPOSE RIGHT) I get all elements in the rigth table with elements that became s tru the condition. I think it must be correct to create this

Comment: @tttrrr please revisit tutorials on `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`. `RIGHT JOIN` will get all the rows from the right table, but it will get only those rows from the left, which have a match in the junction table.

Answer (score 0):

I would join starting with the junction table `TransactionOperation`, then left joining out to the two other tables:

```
CREATE VIEW title AS
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.id_transaction, 'NA')   AS id_transaction,
    COALESCE(t.name_transaction, 'NA') AS name_transaction,
    COALESCE(o.id_operation, 'NA')     AS id_operation,
    COALESCE(o.name_operation, 'NA')   AS name_operation
FROM TransactionOperation to
LEFT JOIN transaction t
    ON t.id_transaction = to.id_transaction
LEFT JOIN operation o
    ON o.id_operation = to.id_operation
```

The problem with your current approach is that is uses an inner join between the junction table and the `transaction` table.  This means that any junction records which do not join to something in the `transaction` table will be dropped, before they have a chance to join to something in the `operation` table.  Using left joins everywhere gets around this problem.

Comment: tim your solution is not work because, I must take also the elements there aren't in transactionOperation. Left join must be RIgth join in your example!

Comment: Then your database design/data is bad.  Your junction table should be the master record of all relationships between transactions and operations, IMO.  If we follow your suggestion, then we risk dropping transaction operations.

Comment: @tttrrr Avoid using `RIGHT JOIN`. It is not a general practice. Prefer `LEFT JOIN` instead; makes it easy to read, understand and follow.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to simply want a `cross join`:

```
select o.id_operation, o.operation_name, t.id_transaction, t.transaction_name
from Transaction t cross join
     Operation o;
```

There is no need for subqueries or for other types of `join`s.